# Spectral gap of Cayley graph of $S_n$ with transpositions is $2/n$.

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

This is exercise 3.5.9 in [Kowalski](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/expander-graphs.pdf).

Given a simple graph $G$, the *Markov averaging operator* $M$ on $G$ is the adjacency matrix, normalized such that each row sums to $1$.

The *normalized spectral gap* $\lambda_1(G)$ is the smallest non-zero eigenvalue of $I-M$.

Let $G_n$ be the Cayley graph of $S_n$, with the generators being all transpositions. The problem is to show that $\lambda_1(G_n)=2/n$.

However, this doesn't appear to be true even for $n=3$. For $G_3$,
$$M=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&1&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues of $I-M$ are $0,1,2$ ($1$ has multiplicity four). The smallest non-zero eigenvalue isn't $2/3$, as expected.

My guess is that I'm misunderstanding the definition of $M$, which is definition 3.2.15 in Kowalski.

Comment: The formula should probably be $\frac{2}{n-1}$ instead, which is experimentally correct at least for $n=2,3,4,5$.

Comment: The eigenvalues are $1 - \frac{\chi((12))}{\text{dim}(\chi)}$ with multiplicity $\text{dim}(\chi)^2$ where $\chi$ runs over the irreducible characters.  So this is saying that the ratio $\frac{\chi((12))}{\text{dim}(\chi)}$ should be maximized in the standard $n-1$ dimensional reflection representation, but it's not immediately clear to me why that is true.